# SQL Update SET sub query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL query like so:

```
UPDATE ScheduleTasks  
SET 
AssignedResource='360 CLEAN'
WHERE (ScheduleID = (SELECT ScheduleID FROM Schedule WHERE Job_No = 'ABC123')) 
AND Description = 'Filing'
```

my issue is that I have another table called `Resource` with a `Resource_ID` and `Resource_Name`  what I am trying to do is update the `scheduleTasks` table with the `Resource_ID` and not the `Resource_Name` which is what `360 CLEAN` is, its `Resource_Name` not `Resource_ID` my question is how can I get the `Resource_ID` From the `Resource_Name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a `sub-query`

```
UPDATE ScheduleTasks
SET    AssignedResource = (SELECT TOP 1 Resource_ID
                           FROM   Resource
                           WHERE  Resource_Name = '360 CLEAN')
WHERE  st.ScheduleID = (SELECT ScheduleID
                        FROM   Schedule
                        WHERE  Job_No = 'ABC123')
       AND st.Description = 'Filing'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by using an `INNER JOIN` on the `UPDATE` statement like so:

```
UPDATE st SET
    AssignedResource = r.Resource_ID
FROM ScheduleTasks st
    -- change join conditions to your preference
    INNER JOIN Resource r on r.Resource_Name = '360 CLEAN'     
WHERE st.Description = 'Filing' AND EXISTS
(
    SELECT s.ScheduleID 
    FROM Schedule s
    WHERE s.Job_No = 'ABC123' AND st.ScheduleID = s.ScheduleID
)
```

Also updated your query for optimizations on checking if the `ScheduleID` from `ScheduleTasks` exists in the `Schedule` table.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update all of the records in the ScheduleTasks (which I recommend) then use:

```
UPDATE ST
SET AssignedResource = R.Resource_ID
FROM ScheduleTasks ST
  INNER JOIN Resource R ON R.Resource_Name = ST.AssignedResource
```

If you want to limit what you update then add a WHERE clause like so:

```
UPDATE ST
SET AssignedResource = R.Resource_ID
FROM ScheduleTasks ST
  INNER JOIN Resource R ON R.Resource_Name = ST.AssignedResource 
  INNER JOIN Schedule S ON S.ScheduleID = ST.ScheduleID 
WHERE ST.AssignedResource = '360 CLEAN'
   AND ST.Description = 'Filing'
   AND S.Job_No = 'ABC123'
```